# Realm incorrect thread error from SyncAdapter

Tags: java, android, multithreading, realm, android-syncadapter

So I have created a very standard sync adapter (using [this fantastic tutorial](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/)) and during `onPerformSync` I run some realm transactions in a method called `syncDatastore` within my `DataManager` class. The issue is when the sync adapter tries to perform the sync, I get

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread.
>   Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.

Here is an excerpt from my `SyncAdapter`:

```
@Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
    try {
        // Get the auth token for the current account
        String authToken = _accountManager.blockingGetAuthToken(account, AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS, true);

        // run network and database operations
        dataManager.syncDatastore();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I initialize the `RealmConfiguration` in my Application class with:

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
```

And an example of how it is used in my `DataManager`:

```
private Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

public void syncDatastore() {
    postResources();
    pushDataToServer();
    getDataFromServer();
}

private void postResources() {
    ArrayList<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();
    clients.addAll(realm.where(Client.class).equalTo("isSynced", false).equalTo("apiId", "0").findAll());
    Log.e("clients count", String.valueOf(clients.size()));
    for (Client c : clients) {
        createClientResource(c);
    }
}
```

Please note I have tried to remove `android:process=":sync"` from my service declaration in the manifest [as outlined here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1083) but to no avail. I am also quite new to both SyncAdapters and Realm, so any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Where does the Realm instance used in this line `clients.addAll(realm.where(Client.class).equalTo("isSynced", false).equalTo("apiId", "0").findAll());` come from? Where is it initialized?

Comment: Please see my edit, in `DataManager`

Comment: oh and your DataManager is instantiated along with Application at some point, so the Realm that belongs to it is on the UI thread. Makes sense. That won't work.

Comment: Well I just followed the realm docs on where to instantiate realm, which is in the Application manager, but this doesn't seem to correspond to how it would work with a sync adapter.

Comment: `onPerformSync` runs on a different thread, so you need to create the Realm instance inside it.

Answer (score 2):

Realm instances are thread confined, so you need a new Realm instance on your background thread (the background thread on which the sync is happening).

```
@Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
    Realm realm = null;
    try {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        // Get the auth token for the current account
        String authToken = _accountManager.blockingGetAuthToken(account, AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS, true);

        // run network and database operations
        dataManager.syncDatastore(realm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
}

public void syncDatastore(Realm realm) {
    postResources(realm);
    pushDataToServer();
    getDataFromServer();
}

private void postResources(Realm realm) {
    RealmResults<Client> clients = realm.where(Client.class).equalTo("isSynced", false).equalTo("apiId", "0").findAll();
    Log.e("clients count", String.valueOf(clients.size()));
    for (Client c : clients) {
        createClientResource(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately using this code gives a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable` error when calling `realm.beginTransaction()` in other methods in `DataManager`

Comment: I should also mention that DataManager is a singleton class. But I don't think that will make any difference.

Comment: the thing is though, syncDatastore doesn't run on a blocking thread, hence why it closes just as soon as it opens in this code.

Comment: Well you're closing it **somewhere** so in order to tell what's up, I'd have to see more of the code

Comment: Wait a second. So you're saying your `onPerformSync` is asynchronous? As per https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.html the `onPerformSync` is running on a background thread, and the logic on it should be synchronous.

Comment: In that case you'll need to open the Realm instance where your Volley request has been executed and you're manipulating its results. :o

Comment: If I post an example of one if my volley requests, would you be so kind as to show me how to handle opening the realm instance therein?

Comment: Well I hope so. Volley is notorious for running the request on the background thread, but the `onSuccess` part of it is on the UI thread, which means that most of this `downloaded stuff => Realm` direction data flow should be a custom request.

Comment: Hi,Were you successful in getting through this. Since I am also planning to use sync adapter along with Realm but little bit confused that I should go ahead or not. Please help.

Comment: What I said in the answer should work without problems. Although Volley is bad for this use case and I recommend Retrofit.